# Chrome no me reconoce @media (min-width: 768px) firefox y edge si

Tags: html, css, responsive, chrome, mediaqueries

Pues lo del titulo, pero en Chorme en las herramientas de desarrollador se ve perfecto, abro la web y no me reconoce las media queries y el tamaño de la fuente se ve enorme.

lo único que he visto es que si en vez de usar 768px utilizo 15em las media queries se aplican pero el tamaño de la fuente es enorme.

Ya he probado 20 combinaciones de meta name="viewport" y ninguna funciona os dejo el código

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>



@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .body__inicio{
    display: none;
  }
  .body__nav{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  top: 12px;
  left: 18px;
}
 .body__nav__ul{
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
 }
  .body__nav__ul__li{
    height: 100%;
  }
 .body__logo{
   right: 18px;
 }
 .h1{
   font-size: 120px;
 }
 .texto{
   margin-left: 0;
   padding-left: 52%;
   width: 30%;
 }
}
```

así es como se ve en las herramientas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y así en Chrome

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Bueno ya me he dado cuenta, resulta que estaba usando una imagen demasiado grande y por algún motivo Chrome me esta poniendo un 250% de zoom cosa que ni Firefox ni Edge hacen.

Comment: Prueba @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){ ....

Comment: Gracias, pero no funciona